# "ValueError: non-default argument follows default argument" when upgrading from Airflow 2.2.2 to 2.8.1

Tags: airflow, airflow-taskflow

Have been doing an upgrade from Airflow 2.2.2 to 2.8.1. All of my DAGs parse after doing relatively minor modifications, except for one.

Using the TaskFlow API, I have a task with this structure:

```py
@task(multiple_outputs=True)
def decorated_task(
    inputs: list[dict],
    logical_date: str,
    project_id: str,
    bucket_name: str,
) -> dict[str, str]:
    # Implementation details
    return {}
```

Being called like this in the DAG:

```py
@dag(
    dag_id=dag_id,
    # ...
    default_args={
        "depends_on_past": False,
        "retries": 3,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(hours=1),
    },
)
def decorated_dag():
    # ...
    task_date = "{{ (dag_run.logical_date - macros.timedelta(days=1)) | ds_nodash }}"
    # ...
    decorated_task_result = decorated_task(
        inputs=inputs,
        logical_date=task_date,
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME,
    )
```

I'm getting this error in the scheduler:

```
ValueError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

with trace:

```
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 3944, in factory
    f(**f_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/dag_file.py", line 160, in decorated_dag
    decorated_task_result = decorated_task(
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/decorators/base.py", line 366, in __call__
    op = self.operator_class(
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 437, in apply_defaults
    result = func(self, **kwargs, default_args=default_args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/decorators/python.py", line 52, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 437, in apply_defaults
    result = func(self, **kwargs, default_args=default_args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/decorators/base.py", line 217, in __init__
    signature = signature.replace(parameters=parameters)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/inspect.py", line 3052, in replace
    return type(self)(parameters,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/inspect.py", line 3008, in __init__
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

It's clearly something internal to Airflow as suggested by the stack trace. I couldn't find anything similar on the Internet nor the GitHub Issues of Airflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the stack trace says, the error comes from this code in the `DecoratedOperator` class in `decorators/base.py`:

```py
# Check the decorated function's signature. We go through the argument
# list and "fill in" defaults to arguments that are known context keys,
# since values for those will be provided when the task is run. Since
# we're not actually running the function, None is good enough here.
signature = inspect.signature(python_callable)
parameters = [
    param.replace(default=None) if param.name in KNOWN_CONTEXT_KEYS else param
    for param in signature.parameters.values()
]
signature = signature.replace(parameters=parameters)
```

The `KNOWN_CONTEXT_KEYS` variable is a long set that represents the Airflow context variables:

```py
KNOWN_CONTEXT_KEYS = {
    "conf",
    # ...
    "logical_date",
    # ...
    
}
```

The `logical_date` context variable is used in our task function signature. From here we can deduce that putting that parameter name at the end of the `decorated_task` function parameter list fixes the issue.

```py
@task(multiple_outputs=True)
def decorated_task(
    inputs: list[dict],
    project_id: str,
    bucket_name: str,
    logical_date: str,
) -> dict[str, str]:
    # Implementation details
    return {}
```

---

#### Update

I made a PR to Airflow to improve the error message on these cases so hopefully it's clearer starting a later minor version of 2.8, or 2.9.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/38015